# pbtxt missing after saving a trained model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

What I am trying to do is to convert my trained CNN to TfLite and use it in my android app. AFAIK I need the .pbtxt in order to freeze the parameters and do the conversion.

However when I save my network using this standard code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=4)
saver.save(sess=session, save_path="some_path", global_step=step)
```

I only get the

```
.data 
.index 
.meta
checkpoint
```

files. No pbtxt.

Is there a way to convert the trained network to tflite without a pbtxt or can I obtain the pbtxt from those files?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply execute:

```
tf.train.write_graph(session.graph.as_graph_def(),
                                     "path",
                                     'model.pb',
                                     as_text=False)
```

to get a .pb or

```
tf.train.write_graph(session.graph.as_graph_def(),
                                     "path",
                                     'model.pbtxt',
                                     as_text=True)
```

to get the text version.